# Pytorch install fails on conda with error as -CondaHTTPError: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for url <https..........>

Tags: anaconda, pytorch

I have installed anaconda 2019 version from repository as the latest version was throwing error on windows 10.
After installing anaconda(conda 4.10.1), i am unable to install Pytorch using command 'conda install pytorch-cpu -c pytorch' on anaconda prompt. It throws below  error. I believe it is trying to look for file 'win-64/pytorch-cpu-1.1.0-py3.7_cpu_1.tar.bz2' and strangely when i check on https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files i can't locate this file. Please help.

Error message :-

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for url https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64/pytorch-cpu-1.1.0-py3.7_cpu_1.tar.bz2
Elapsed: 01:00.706682

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, but it turned out the error message was misleading. In my case extending the remote connection timeout parameter in the condarc file fixed the issue